# Redirect or Die? Are these die statements helpful?

Tags: php, cakephp

Inherited a Cakephp application which uses a great deal of `$this->redirect($url)` statements; all of them are followed by `die();` as follows:

```
$this->redirect($url);
die();
```

I can only assume this is some poor form of error trapping, but I can't see why this would ever be necessary. `$this->redirect` uses a URL redirect function from my framework, nothing our application has altered; if it doesn't work then my framework doesn't work, so nothing on the whole site would work in the first place. The die(); statements make it very hard to weed through the code and find where errors were expected (they're not using exceptions of course).

Is there any reason to keep these? The only functionality I can imagine they provide is to prevent execution of logic beyond a redirect in a function that wasn't supposed to execute, but it looks like bad unnecessary coding to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the source . `function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true)` the `$exit` is default true and `@param boolean $exit If true, exit() will be called after the redirect`

Comment: For some god forsaken reason in my version of CakePHP that function has $exit=false and all the security and functionality issues that results in. I hate to do it, but I've changed it myself since the upgrade will result in the `$exit=true` functionality anyway. Thanks for reminding me to peek in the source.

Comment: In CakePHP 1.1 the exit wasn't called by default, but from 1.2 up it exits after a redirect automatically.

Answer (score 3):

They are helpful. Without `die()`, script is executed to the end and after that you're redirected.

Imagine script with 20 database queries. Before first query, you have for example

```
if ($_GET['redirNow']){
   $this->redirect($url);
   die();
}
```

It won't do any queries. Without `die()`, it will do all 20 queries.

Comment: He can add die() to his function.

Comment: @Mchl Why is this sloppy? I think in PHP this is perfectly fine. I realise that it doesn't follow very high 'code flow' standards, but hey, this is PHP...

Comment: I thought this wasn't true as redirect is supposed to call `exit()` each time, but apparently cakephp 1.1 didn't have this functionality, and I'm in a 1.2 alpha and I don't know if this is the case or not. All the more reason to keep trying to update this monstrocity.

Comment: @PElle ten Cate it's _extremely_ sloppy, but unfortunately this whole source is the opposite of best practices, this is just another thing I'll have to wait to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirection is done using header() then there's a very good reason for using die(). By some programming error, if some data is sent to the browser before the redirect, the redirect will fail. It's better to exit at that stage rather than execute the rest of the script which is not meant to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

You're right. It's better to use an error handler and logging mechanism. Take a look at this article:

http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die

Comment: This isn't the case here. In the question `die()` is used to actually prevent any other script execution after redirect header is set by `$this->redirect()`.

Comment: An exception would also prevent further execution (up to the catch block). If my framework failed redirecting, I would want to know when and why it has failed.

Comment: I bet you would. My point is Daniel's article is about very specific usage of `or die()` idiom. The' `die()` after redirection header' is kind of more valid, but still I'll call it sloppy ;)